# postgreSQLで検索項目がNULL(未設定)でなければ曖昧検索を行う

Tags: javascript, postgresql

検索画面で設定した項目をもとにpostgreSQLからデータを取ってくる
という処理をjavascriptで行っています。

以下のようなSQLを発行するとuserIdが"NULL"の場合は全件、"001"の場合は"001"のレコードを取得することができました。

```
var userId = '001';
var sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = COALESCE('"+ userId + "', user_id);";
```

これを利用しuserIdに"1"が設定された場合、は"1"で曖昧検索を行い、
"NULL"が設定された場合は全件検索を行いたいのですが可能でしょうか。

以下のような分岐を使う方法では項目が多い場合などコード量が増えてしまうのでなるべく避けたいです。

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info "
if (userId != null) {
   sql = sql + "WHERE user_id ='" + userId + "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問どおりの動作をするSQL文は、次のようになるかと思います。
(PostgreSQL9.4.5では動作しましたが、標準SQL準拠かどうかは自信がありません)

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE 
           CASE '" + userId + "'='null' THEN 'a'='a'
           ELSE user_id LIKE '%" + userId + "%'
           END;";
```

SQLのCASE式で条件分岐をかけています。
 - javascript変数"userId"がnullの場合は「'a'='a'」が条件式となるので全レコード抽出
 - そうでなければ「user_id LIKE '%(userIdの内容)%'」が条件式となるので、「(userIdの内容)」を「含む」user_idのレコードを抽出
となります。

ただし、userIdの内容を厳密にチェックしないとインジェクションし放題ですので、
SQL文を組み立てる前に不正文字が含まれていないかチェックする処理は必須と思います。
あるいは、placeholderが利用できるSQL実行環境を選択すべきかと思います。

Comment: user20098 さん 回答いただきありがとうございます！この方法で1度試してみたいと思います

Comment: 変数のチェックは同じく必要ですが、CASE式無しでも。`var sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE '"+ userId + "' = '' OR user_id LIKE '%" + userId + "%';";`

Answer (score 0):

where句を生成するヘルパー関数を導入するのがよいと思います

```js
function whereCondition(colName, value) {
  if (value === null) {
    return '';
  } else {
    return `${colName} = ${value}`;
  }
}

function whereClause(...whereConditions) {
  whereConditions = whereConditions.filter(Boolean);
  if (whereConditions.length) {
    return `WHERE ${whereConditions.join(' AND ')}`;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

const null_element = null;
const user_id = 17;
// need single quote
const user_name = `'WildChinsuko'`;

// WHERE 
console.info(
  whereClause(
    whereCondition('does_not_appear', null_element),
    whereCondition('user_id', user_id),
    whereCondition('user_name', user_name)
  )
);
```

手作りライブラリを使うよりも、しっかりテストがなされたライブラリを利用する方が安心かと思います
JavaScriptで書かれたSQL Query Builderライブラリはいろいろあると思うので、探してみてください

Comment: gocho さん回答いただきありがとうございます。SqlQueryBuilderというのがあるんですね！参考になりました！

Comment: @WildChinsuko SQL Query Builder は "SQL文組み立てプログラム" という意味です
有名なものに Squel.js があるようです
https://hiddentao.com/squel/